# Balloon3D in Pharo

Tags: pharo

Balloon3D seams to be the only 3D engine that can use Direct3D as a backend.

I would like to import it into Pharo, but all my attempts so far have failed. I managed to get it partially working, by using "Squeak3D.dll"; however, the lighting and textures don't work.

According to [Pharo - the collaborActive book: 3D Graphics and OpenGL](http://pharo.gemtalksystems.com/book/LanguageAndLibraries/3DGraphicsAndOpenGL/) Balloon3D works in Pharo.

If you have any ideas that would help, please let me know.

I'm using Pharo 3.0 on a Windows 10 64-bit laptop.

Comment: Citation from the linked book: "Balloon3D is a renderer for Squeak written entirely in Smalltalk that provides many features in an OO way, **but seems to be outdated and not maintained any more.**"
You should try other Pharo versions, e.g. 2.0. It's likely that Balloon3D worked with one specific version. If you need help with porting Balloon3D to the newest Pharo version you should get onto the development list or Slack channel. We'll be happy to help.